# issues with angular to call api input via parameters

Tags: angular, api, parameters, angular9

I am trying to fetch data from the API server using angular 9 bypassing id in the input from to get the phone value from JSON in the API. in this mount that not working with me :(, I don't know what the problem even I use the same format in JSON API. 
like this one

> this.phone = this.results.address.phone
>   Please, I need someone to guide me for the right answer.

thank you :)

I live a simple of my work down!

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from  '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}
url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1';
id='';
phone='';
results : any;
getsearcha(){
  this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+this.id)
  .subscribe(

    data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
      this.phone = this.results.address.phone
     console.log(this._http.get(this.url));
    })
}
}
```

as well the is my app.component.html

```
<h1> test app</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=id>

<button (click)="getsearcha()">Click</button>
<hr>
phone{{phone}}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dryp3b

Answer (score 2):

Your API return only data.data['result'] is incorrect.

```
 { "id": 2,"name": "Ervin Howell","username": "Antonette","email":"Shanna@melissa.tv","address": {
"street": "Victor Plains",
"suite": "Suite 879",
"city": "Wisokyburgh",
"zipcode": "90566-7771",
"geo": {
  "lat": "-43.9509",
  "lng": "-34.4618"
}},"phone": "010-692-6593 x09125","website": "anastasia.net","company": {"name": "Deckow-Crist","catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency","bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized you are handling your response incorrectly. So I modified the code as you can see below.

I checked jsonplacerholde.typicode.com API and realized that users' service doesn't receive a numeric value. The users' service returns 10 users, therefore I removed id from the HTTP request.

app.component.ts

```
getsearcha(){
  // this service doesn't receive a numeric value
  this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      // data is an array of users, so I get the first element with [0]
      this.results = data;
      this.phone = this.results[0].phone
    })
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
 test app
</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id">

<button (click)="getsearcha()">Click</button>
<hr>
phone {{phone}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all once you hit the API , your entire response is coming in 'data' itself so no need to do the following:

```
  this.results = data['results'];
```

Instead do:

```
  this.results = data;
  this.phone = this.results[(id-1)].phone // did (id-1) because indexing is 
  from 0 and for id=2 you'll have appropriate result on index (2-1 i.e 1 and so on).
```

Except that everything is good with your code.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

According to  jsonplacerholde.typicode.com/users/{{id}}, It not returning you any array, it is simple object so change subsribe function to below one

```
getsearcha(){
  this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+this.id)
  .subscribe((userData:any) => {
      this.phone = userData.phone;
    });
}
```

Good to go